# Is it OK to indicate that I downvoted in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

This is from my Flagging Summary:

> [Me:] Where did my comment go? It was a factual explanation for the -1, and I did keep it strictly neutral in tone. – 7 hours ago
>
> [Mod:] declined - Comments regarding upvotes/downvotes/acceptance rate are *noise* on the Stack Exchange network and are removed.

**The comment in question:**

> -1 because this is a very inefficient and inappropriate way to simulate SpinWait(). The library offers much better solutions with 1 call. Like `Sleep()`.

Now this is from a Q+A where the tone was getting a little nasty, so I don't mind the actual delete so much (though the very bad self-answer is still up).

But should I really take it from this (template?) response that the explanation of a downvote is noise and unwelcome?

Comment: Right, and was your comment the *only* comment that was deleted?

Comment: There was indeed another comment in response that devolved into name-calling; both were deleted.

Comment: `Sleep()`...  Really?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - `Sleep(:-)`? Yes, did you look at the alternative?

Comment: I still don't know which question we're talking about. :)

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Well, that guy was already itching for a confrontation, based on the answer he posted.  I removed the editorial content.  You're right; if you're just trying to simulate work, `Thread.Sleep()` works quite nicely.

Comment: Right, I wanted to avoid [specific question] here.

Comment: @mmyers  "both were deleted" - yes, but with a few hours in between. My comment was deleted on its own, not as part of a major cleanup.

Comment: @ChrisF I think this one is quite distinct

Comment: Ok really?!?! This entire thing is because he added "-1" to the comment and didn't just leave it as a suggestion as to how to improve the answer?!?! That is noise! But a 5 page discussion on "why that is noise" is not? I personally will never stop telling people ***why*** I downvoted them. Because I get ***uber annoyed*** when people downvote me with no explanation as per why *they think* my answer is incorrect. (note: any name calling that followed should have been removed.. relevant comments such as the one outlined should not have been)

Comment: @rlemon Why do you get annoyed? I understand in very small amount of cases but in majority you can just read the question you are "answering" more carefully, run the code in your answer and there's the explanation. I get furious when someone asks me to explain downvote when they either completely misunderstood the question or posted code that doesn't work and/or doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @Esailija: http://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/220201648453193728 One of a million such out there.

Comment: On occasion I see a down-voted question or answer with a comment along the lines of, "I didn't downvote you, but [this is what's wrong with your post]". If anything, that's to avoid contention over the voting, but it's still a reference to the voting. Is that, too, considered noise?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> -1 this is incorrect

is essentially noise. Your downvote should already indicate this; if your downvote indicates anything other than "something here is incorrect or unhelpful", you're doing it wrong.

> -1 this code contained live bobcat, would not compile again

is better, but honestly the comment should simply **explain what's incorrect in an answer, not focus on the voting**. I don't know what your comment was, but that's the guideline I'd follow. Don't include the "-1" and people will focus on the correctness of the post (which is good) not the score of their post (which is only the means to an end).

Posts regarding voting and acceptance rate are very contentious and *focus on the wrong problem*. In this case it sounds like your comment shouldn't have been deleted, but if in the future you don't even reference voting I think you'd be much safer.

Comment: But everybody is always complaining about 'downvotes w/o explanation'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: An idea which is consistently dismissed as unworkable, as the numerous declined feature requests forcing people to explain their downvotes attest.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I understand it shouldn't be compelled, but linking your criticism to a dv seems constructive.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Actually I would prefer if people did provide their explanation for the downvote, but without saying that they downvoted.  As Ben says, it's about the post, not the vote.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Personally speaking, I've never had someone ask "Why the downvote?" when I've left out the `-1` and just purely given my critique of the post.

Comment: I hate down-votes without an explanation. I'd rather have "you're a f***ing tool, because ____" than no comment at all. If someone posts a legitimate critique of the post, I don't really care if they're also the one who down-voted. I can take it in stride and improve the post, or I can live with it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman more to the point, they should be wondering what's wrong with their post; the problem is without comments, downvotes are the only way to see that something is wrong. Giving them the comment solves this problem even if you don't admit to a downvote; maybe you're just correcting them and didn't downvote at all! Should it matter? Correct is correct.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I salute you, sir. The problem is all the users who take downvotes personally and react strongly; it's better to skirt around that problem as much as possible. Though I'm sure we'd all love to eliminate it directly, I don't see a way to do so.

Comment: It is also conceivable (and maybe even preferable) to completely and intentionally separate the two. If someone asks "why the down-vote?" before you've actually added your constructive comment (because you have a constructive comment, right?), you can probably say something like "Perhaps it's because..." and then provide the reasons. This gives the OP who reacts quickly the criticism they need, without a target to inflict their fury. You can even be pro-active, and lie a little - "I wasn't the one who down-voted, but here are some reasons they might have..." This is a white lie IMHO.

Comment: PS that doesn't mean that if you see me do that, that's what happened. I also make sure to do that when it wasn't me who down-voted, too. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand as cathartic as it would be to know some guy downvoted because he hates your face, those comments aren't helpful to keep around (and really should be removed for rudeness if they are actually written to that effect)

Comment: BTW, as a side note, if we see "Why the downvote?" comments we usually delete those outright, as pretty much *nothing* good comes of it.

Comment: I'm sitting next to the CEO of my company, trying desperately not to snort at `contained a live bob cat.`

Comment: "-1 This is incorrect" can be useful; it identifies that the issue is not irrelevance, personal opinion, vagueness/unclarity, but incorrectness.  And sometimes people have better things to do than to figure out which aspect of a statement is incorrect.  If you get "-1 This is incorrect", be thankful for the (admittedly a bit vague) feedback, which is better than the more common "no feedback" that people often get, and check for complete accuracy.

Comment: While it may be better to just explain what the problem is and not indicate the downvote, IMO it's definitely _worse_ to just lose the explanation altogether merely to avoid the indication of a downvote. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307414/196834

Comment: Related to the discussion happening here in the comments: [What can/should be done about "this doesn't work" comments with no explanation/elaboration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385247/997587)

Answer (score 31):

I think it highly depends on the comment:

**Good:**

- -1, that cannot work because of xyz
- -1, that's just a dirty hack/workaround and does not solve the actual issue of the OP

**Bad:**

- -1, this is bad/wrong
- -1, learn some english!
- -1, you have a funny nose

Comment: Although generally, we should refrain from the "+/-1" aspects of the comment, as they don't add anything to the question.  The rest of the comment was valid, and I should have edited it in retrospect.

Comment: Looking at your avatar, the last one comes from personal experience?

Comment: -100, you insulted the allmighty octocat!

Comment: It all depends on the context. E.g. if someone maintains that C++ is descended from Eiffel, I would just downvote and explain "-1 this is incorrect". What more can be said? Recapitulate the history of programming languages? I react to this advocacy for for mechanical rules. It is insulting to the SO readership, since it implies that a fair percentage of them are unable to do think.

Comment: Given that such an answer would be some pretty obvious trolling, I'd guess most moderators responding to it would skip your comment and go straight to deleting the post itself, @Alf.

Comment: Everyone knows C++ descended from PHP through the means of time travel which will be invented in 2015.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags That is not true: During 2016, I will go back in time, showing to Bjarne Stroustrup a snippet written in Objective-C. I can tell you because I am returning from my time travel, and I stopped on this year to tell myself the numbers to play on lottery.

Comment: -1, It'd be better without -1's

Answer (score 20):

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment describes the legitimate use cases for comments.

They are:

- Requesting clarification from the author;
- Leaving constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Adding relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

That's it.  Notice that discussions about voting are not in the list.

Explaining the reason you are downvoting is perfectly fine, but it's not necessary to indicate that you downvoted.  It's about the post, not about the votes.  Stating that you downvoted them is contentious, and invites discussions that you don't really want or need to engage in.

Comment: I added a link, and I have to say I think this falls into the second case.

Comment: @mmyers: Yeah, but not the -1.

Comment: Isn't the -1 prefix just shorthand for "I down-voted because..."? I realize that the rules state that shouldn't be there, but why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Because tying your comment to a downvote opens you up to a contentious argument that could have been avoided.  People don't like being downvoted; it stings.

Comment: I guess it all depends on the target. If there is a single down-vote and I know it's tied to the constructive reason given, there shouldn't be any contention at all. Whereas if the comment just has constructive criticism, I may feel that the down-vote came from a different person, for a different reason...

Comment: Every time I've explained my downvote after an OP requested it, I wound up in an argument with them, so I don't do it anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well I've made it a personal policy to not down-vote without a comment (unless there is already a comment that reflects the spirit of my down-vote). How can a user improve if they've been down-voted but no explanation?

Comment: @AaronBertrand You can still provide the explanation, just don't say -1.

Comment: I feel like we're talking in circles.

Comment: I don't recall ever getting into an argument because I said "-1". The few discussions I've had about downvoting were due to a disagreement about my reasons.

Comment: @John I agree, I'd suspect there would be very little argument if you had a legitimate reason to accompany the -1. I think the guideline is there to protect everyone from the unreasonable few.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if I tell someone their post was not good because of x, or they should take x into account because of y, or any other suggestion -- if they disagree, and perceive it as criticism, they're going to argue with me whether or not my comment was prefixed with "-1"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Perhaps.  I can only tell you my personal experience; I only get the lengthy argument when they know I downvoted them.

Comment: We've argued more here than I've ever argued with anyone on SO, and I didn't even down-vote you *or* prefix a comment with "-1" :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Suffice it to say there are good reasons why the system makes voting anonymous, the same reasons that one might want to stay behind that cloak of anonymity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I understand that. That doesn't mean they have to be anonymous in all cases. Most people don't comment at all and just drive-by down-vote, for fear of retaliation that may or may not come, and I don't think we'll ever see eye-to-eye on which side of the fence this should fall.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Nobody's forcing anyone to go one way or the other.  But if the conversation gets contentious, no one should be surprised if the comments get nuked from orbit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey my only concern is that someone reading this thread may think, hey, a moderator down-votes without commenting, so I will too! It's not about force, it's about implying what is good and/or acceptable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I do comment when I downvote, I just don't disclose that I'm the downvoter.  It's not a relevant detail.

Comment: I agree with that, but it doesn't line up with your comment above, which can be construed as "I just don't bother commenting anymore."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: To be more accurate, I do not respond to requests for downvote explanations.  I don't say "I downvoted because..."

Comment: `Every time I've explained my downvote after an OP requested it, I wound up in an argument with them, so I don't do it anymore` And this, folks, is precisely why voting is anonymous.

Comment: @JP So, its better to hide behind your actions? Wy is better decision to allow anonymous downvoting, so anyone can downvote a question, just because their answer was declined with explanation? Downvoter: "(S)He tells me that my answer is not an appropriate, who the hell is (S)he, you have -1 from me, its free, and noone knows its me".

Comment: @Robert Harvey And would you like to know if someone downvoted your answer, why it's downvoted, or you don't care about other peoples opinions/thoughts)?

Comment: @Goran This isn't a court of law, where you have the right to face your accuser. This issue has been brought up several times on meta. In short, it would effectively kill downvoting. Forcing downvoters to reveal themselves would expose them to revenge downvoting. This site would quickly devolve.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I hope you don't mind if I continue to admit that I'm the downvoter. Although I agree that one should not be required to explain downvoting, or to acknowledge that one has downvoted, it should be a matter of choice. I choose in most cases to say that I have downvoted, and why. I have rarely regretted this choice in my three years on these sites.

Comment: @JP True that there could be side effects, but surely in the form they are now, they also have side effects. I am not sure what you mean by revenge downvoting, since they also need to have explanation. If explanation is clearly wrong, then it could lead to punishment for revenge downvoter, maybe denying the right to downvote, or anything. As long everything is open, these revenge downvotes do not have future.

Comment: -1 because when i downvoted your above explanation of why downvote comments should be removed, i got a notification to please add a comment explaining how youranswer could be improved. i think you just want attention.

Comment: @John: it is a matter of choice. That said, I've responded to quite a few complaints regarding revenge voting from folks who did expose their votes in this way, and I'd wager most of the SO mods have seen quite a few more. It doesn't take long to realize that, whatever the intention of the author, such comments *do* tend to stir up more trouble (whether that's arguments, flags, or revenge-votes) than they've any reason to, and either edit or delete them on site. But when such drama *doesn't* arise, there's no reason to assume they wouldn't be left alone.

Comment: This is bovine excrements. The whole web is full of ___high-rep users whining about anonymous downvoters___ on Stackoverflow. As Alf noted, at the beginning, when you downvote, ___you are asked to explain your downvote.___ And that's what I do: ___If I downvote, I either upvote an existing comment explaining the problem, or I add my own comment___ saying "`-1`, because...". I used to not to do that, and I got involved in arguments more often than I am now, because now, ___if it comes to name-calling, I either ignore or flag___ the comments for deletion. Being sneaky buys you nothing.

Comment: @sbi: I agree.  Stack Overflow is being destroyed before our eyes.

Comment: Oh, the drama...

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach The suggestion is to leave a comment explaining in which way the post can be improved. Leaving a comment such as "-1 I don't like this answer" is not very constructive.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: why are you addressing these obvious observations to me? it sounds like you're trying to convey to other readers a false impression that i have advocated what you say is "not very constructive". if so, and i can't think of any other reason for stating the obvious and adressing it to a person, then let me teach that there is an English word for trying to make others believe what you don't believe yourself (namely, a lie). in addition, there is commonly known two-word latin expression when the attempt involves conveying a negative impression of a person (ad hominem).

Comment: I never put the "-1 because..." on any of my comments (AFAIK), I only explain what works or doesn't work on the post. But I _HATE_ it when I happen to be the first to comment on a post that gets downvoted and the owner goes berserk on me because "I downvoted them".  It's a lose-lose situation.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Because you wrote the following, in [your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138189/is-it-ok-to-indicate-that-i-downvoted-in-a-comment/138192#comment388489_138192): "-1 because when i downvoted your above explanation of why downvote comments should be removed, i got a notification to please add a comment explaining how your answer could be improved." The explanation doesn't need to contain "-1" which would be purely noise. Also, this is not an [ad hominem attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem).

Comment: The grand irony, of course, is that most of these comments could be deleted based on those criteria. Comments should have a bit more flexibility than exactly what's in the FAQ. Downvotes should require explanations or shouldn't be anonymous, IMO. It's the same reason I use my RL name. Can you imagine how much of a PITA I'd be if I didn't?

Comment: @Jeff: SO you just made my point: If they get miffed even if you don't downvote, or do not admit it, why not admitting it right away? What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Erik: As much a PITA as the hundreds of thousands of other who do not use their real name?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: ok, you leave me the choice of believing that you're unable to understand what i wrote but just stumbled on a clever way of conveing a misleading negative impression by saying literally true things that a reader would find meaningless without assuming that the related to the person you addressed the comment to, OR, much simpler, i can believe that you're **again** trying to convey a falsehood in a clever way. guess what i believe?

Answer (score 4):

It may have been a general clean-up of many of the comments against that post, especially if - as you say - the conversation was going downhill.

I've had some tangible comments deleted as part of such a sweep before. Overall, it's better, and I don't expect a mod to pick through every single comment in a heated follow-up discussion to try and pick out the salient parts. Just clean it up.

Hopefully the person who received the -1 had time to read your explanation, if it was constructive. If it wasn't constructive, well... remember that you may have felt it was constructive, but a mod reviewing it (or community members flagging it) may have felt differently.

Personally, I still explain down-votes, but as others suggested I have been trying to be better about prefacing it with a -1. It doesn't really matter if I'm the one leaving the comment *and* I'm the one down-voting it; the meat is that here is a suggestion to improve your post.

I think I'm a little more reluctant to leave out a +1 on a comment I have for an answer I generally agree with but have a suggestion to make it a little bit better. Just so that they know I felt their answer was helpful even if I am not just saying "right on" but also providing some constructive criticism.

Comment: The OP did read it, and basically told me to answer or stfu. Like I said, I don't need this one undeleted so badly.

Comment: Well that's just a bad user, or maybe a good user having a bad day. I don't think that should dictate how you behave on SO in general, just like if someone down-votes you for a stupid reason and says so, you don't stop posting. This seems like an edge case, not the norm.

Comment: Yeah, leaving the +1 isn't nearly so contentious. I've never seen anyone flipout "WTF Why you upvote my crappy post?"

Comment: @BenBrocka right but it highlights an inconsistency in the policy^H^H^H^H^H^H guidelines.

Comment: I'm just trying to help solve the social problem. And worst-case I'd rather people err on making the body of their comments *comments* rather than prefixing the vote on all of them

Comment: Oh I agree, just stating that the wording "Comments regarding upvotes/downvotes" is better suited to one set of comments than another. Also aside from the simple +1 stuff are questions like "Why did you accept that answer rather than mine?" I point out when there is an obvious flaw in the accepted answer, both for the OP's benefit and for future readers. And I try to resist asking when a later, identical answer is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

My view is similar, but slightly more strict, than that of [@ThiefMaster's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138190/196834):

#### Good/acceptable downvote-comments

- -1: This approach cannot work because of XYZ.
- -1: This answer is too verbose and encyclopedic, it should be slimmed down.
- -1: It's not clear to me how this answer differs in essencefrom @SomeUser 's earlier answer.

#### Bad downvote-comments *and why they're bad in italics*

- -1: While on the subject, this does not provide an actual answer to OP's specific question.
         <sub>*This would be a reason to flag, not downvote*</sub>
- -1, that's just a dirty hack/workaround and does not solve the actual issue of the OP 
         <sub>*Too acrimonious  / antagonistic*</sub>
- -1, this is bad/wrong 
         <sub>*No useful info in this comment*</sub>
- -1, learn some English! 
         <sub>*Commenter should at least give specific examples of poor grammar, and better yet - edit and correct it.*</sub>
- -1, you have a funny nose 
         <sub>*Oh yeah? Well you have funny ears!*</sub>

Answer (score -4):

Obviously I am missing part of the larger issue surrounding this specific case (name calling, ect) however the core of the question remains: Should comments that discuss voting be removed?

Short answer: **No**

Long(er) answer: **NO** <sub>with a butt!</sub>
If the comment merley mentions that the vote was + or - ***BUT*** also gives a reasoning to why the vote was cast I don't see this as being any different that just posting the advice and leaving it at that... except for the fact that (in my personal experience) if the user felt strongly enough to -1 ***AND*** comment why, they are willing to +1 after you have taken their advice and updated your question. I have had a few cases where this landed me +++rep and a check!

Now, if the comment is useless `-1 this is wrong` then I can understand why it is deleted... that is akin to deleting `Yo, what up brotha` type comments. They do not offer any substance and *are clutter*.  However even the tiniest bit of information here would turn that bad comment into a helpful one (like in the case of the OP's comment).

Anyways, that is my two cents.

<sub>Disclaimer: I expect a comment+reasoning for ALL downvotes to this answer! No acceptions!</sub>

Comment: -1 That disclaimer is begging people to downvote you and then explain the downvote. I hope you *accept* that this is not an *exception* to that rule

Comment: without a doubt! this is also the best part about meta. :) I will take my downvotes with a smile.