# Don't put +1 in comments

Tags: discussion

Browsing across many posts on stackoverflow and meta, I have noticed that lots of people put +1 or -1 in their comments (the former much more). This may cause people to downvote or upvote another person based on how they voted on their post. Since votes are private on stackoverflow, should they not remain private?

Comment: -1 If we want to reveal our vote, why not?

Comment: I like the irony

Comment: First post I've seen on meta that is actually trying to discourage commenting on votes compared to the hundreds that want to force people to comment on downvotes

Comment: Well, you gave it in a golden plate ;)

Comment: This earlier discussion took a more constructive turn than this post seems doomed to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138189/166936 . But yeah, +1 is stupid, if something is good about an answer, just say that. Same for downvotes. The number is just back patting/flaggelation

Comment: @psubsee2003 I see very few people complaining "WHY DID YOU AHOLES UPVOTE MY QUESTION WTF RAGEQUIT"

Comment: I hate sites that don't have -1, everyone is happy or anodyne.

Comment: downvoting is fine, just don't put '-1' on it

Comment: @scrblnrd3 I don't care for it either, but I get it. It's usually to stop people from whining. Often this happens: I downvote and leave a related comment (sans "-1"). User replies to my comment, then posts another one like "@downvoter care to explain?" rolleyes.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Votes are private, but you are free to comment on a post regarding your vote. (Please note that a +1/-1 comment can be added without a vote).

Comment: Some people even write +1 and -1 in their comments without *actually* voting. `-->`