# Closing topics on Stack Overflow without reason

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions, off-topic, not-constructive

A question of mine was recently closed on Stack Overflow.

[My closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637289/building-browser-based-games) was not off-topic, it wasn't a poll or a discussion. I put in things I researched upon, it wasn't vague. It asked for alternatives to an implementation issue which is completely within the scope defined in FAQs by Stack Overflow.

The first guy, Wooble, who commented and downvoted - didn't even read the question properly. I specifically said that I was looking for alternatives, not necessarily to be coded in Python.

And even upon being asked in comments, the downvoters didn't care to explain. (The last downvoter downvoted after the comment was there, before the question was closed).

There has already been discussion on meta very recently upon the same topic.

[Off-topic-close-reasons-to-op](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op)

I would like to hence bring forth the topic again and stress highly upon it. This is not constructive behavior in any sense as it only leads to frustration on OP's part having no reason for the question to be closed.

Why can't we make a comment necessary before down-voting? Apologies, if I am re-surfacing the topic again in a very short span of time, but I believe that given people are still practicing the destructive behavior, it doesn't reflect well on the SO moderation committee as a whole.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the SO moderation committee as a whole." Certain reputation levels unlock certain moderation abilities.

Comment: "Anyone has any ideas?" is probably something you should avoid in your questions. It is not easy to give a correct answer to that.

Comment: "the SO moderation committee" Oh oh oh oh oh, can we call it "the Board of Silliness"?!

Comment: **Nobody** expects the Stack Overflow Moderation Committee! Our primary weapon is surprise! Surprise and closing questions...

Comment: *This is not constructive behavior* Are you talking about not bothering to read the close reason? Then yes I agree that's not constructive.

Comment: Whenever someone runs to meta re their question there's always one sympathiser. //`reopen (1/5)`

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: The OP can cast their own reopen vote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wow, never did know that; seems silly on the face of it.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I stopped wondering...there are so many people on SO which just allow *everything*. Nearly every question which gets downvoted into oblivion has upvotes mixed into it...it's sad somehow.

Comment: Wait...OPs can cast reopen votes on their own questions? That's absurd! May as well just do away with that and change the reopen threshold from 5 votes to 4.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Indeed, recently I notice quite literally _any_ question can get at least one up-vote. Either bots are winning or humans are slowly becoming yet more retarded, unthinking animals.

Comment: Your question is asking for a lot.  You want multi-core support in a browser using the Python language, and I didn't even think Python was well-suited for that anyway.  It's kinda like asking "I want to travel to town on my blender.  How can I do that?  I tried the BlenderCar object, but it didn't work."

Comment: @JackManey If you assume for that OPs do have some degree of intelligence, then the reopen vote for the OP does make sense. If I found my answer in a duplicate, I wouldnt cast a reopen vote. If I didnt, then I would.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You need to initialize the Engine first, the Electrical- and Gasoline-Implementations work best at the moment. Though, If you feel adventurous, you could use the Nuclear-Implementation. Also always funny is the Donkey-Implementation...also don't forget to initialize four tires!

Comment: @AshRj Obviously the OP would think it should be re-opened, they posted the damn thing. There's a bias.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: When did the masses outgrow the unthinking animals state? Also, if in doubt an OP should be allowed to vote, because there *are users* which fix their posts (my brother had a friend who knew a guy whose uncle cousin had seen that once).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Not in every case. Slight bias, yes. Going by your logic, a person who then casts a close vote on his own question would be outright insane ? ;) Yet, the system allows that, and people do.

Comment: @AshRj - You wouldn't, but I'd almost be willing to bet precious parts of my anatomy that most users would.

Comment: @JackManey I wouldn't generalize without specific data/numbers. Users who understand closing/reopening would have some degree of experience in the network, otherwise they wouldn't stick around to cast a reopen vote. So, its safe to assume, that a certain fraction would use the feature correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: If I'm not mistaken, questions with close/reopen votes are pushed onto a review queue...so that makes sense in my opinion.

Comment: *"leads to frustration on OPs part"* - Your feelings have no bearing on whether or not something is appropriate for SO. Your question *causes* frustration for the rest of the users.

Comment: @AshRj - The point is that there are very few reasons why an OP with a closed question wouldn't vote to reopen it. If anything, the OP shouldn't have the ability to cast a reopen vote on his/her question, even if s/he has over 3,000 rep.

Comment: @Robert But! Will it blend?!

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby There may be merit in the feature, I haven't thought about it in any practical or philosophical sense, just taking it at face value at the moment, and can't see it. I do think it matters, however, that users moderating the review queue won't necessarily be aware that the one vote is the OPs.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: To be honest, I spend pretty much to zero time in those queues, but seeing who casted the vote would be nifty to have for sure (if not already there).

Comment: @JackManey 25% of closed posts are closed as exact duplicates, 10% are closed as off-topic http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105000/percentage-of-closed-posts-with-close-reason-exact-duplicate, http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105000/percentage-of-closed-posts-with-close-reason-off-topic . So, assuming reasonable users, 35% of the users wont cast an unnecessary reopen vote which is a reasonable percentage to argue for having this feature, IMO.

Comment: @AshRj - I'm not sure your assumption of 100% reasonable users holds. Even if it did, 65% of users with a closed question would most likely cast a reopen vote. That seems like a poor reason to implement this feature, IMO.

Comment: @AshRj - And after a bit more thought, why would none of those 35% whose questions are closed as off-topic or duplicates cast reopen votes?

Comment: [Criminey, and now there are two reopen votes....](http://picardfacepalm.com) And an upvote. Seriously?

Comment: @JackManey I am not talking in absolutes, just saying its less likely. Duplicate ones would probably find answers in the linked thread. Off-topic ones would be directed to the appropriate sites.

Answer (score 14):

Your question wasn't closed as being Off-Topic, it was closed as being Not Constructive.  Specifically, you were asking for recommendations, and as the close reason states:

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion

If people want to comment when downvoting, that's fine, but it is not required.

From "[Is it OK to indicate that I downvoted in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138189/is-it-ok-to-indicate-that-i-downvoted-in-a-comment)" (specifically, [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138189/is-it-ok-to-indicate-that-i-downvoted-in-a-comment)):

> Explaining the reason you are downvoting is perfectly fine, but it's not necessary to indicate that you downvoted. It's about the post, not about the votes. Stating that you downvoted them is contentious, and invites discussions that you don't really want or need to engage in.

Comment: `"-1 - [Insert reason here]" was chatty and not constructive ` - wow, really? How so? Indicating that you're a downvoter and giving a reason doesn't sound like a "not constructive" thing to me. Sounds like it's giving the poster a chance to fix and get you to revoke your vote.

Comment: I have seen dozens of questions on SO asking for recommendations in implementation. Isn't that what its there for?

Comment: @Sylar - No. No, it is not. Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine.

Comment: So, all those questions asking for help..recommending a book on some topic, possible implementation issues - they all fall under recommendation. Why are they not closed then?

Comment: @Sylar: Provide us with Links and we'll answer that with deeds.

Comment: @Sylar - They aren't closed because there are only so many people who are able to cast close votes... Some bad questions slip through the cracks.

Comment: @Sylar go find some.  I'll bet that many of them are actually closed

Comment: @Sylar - There are lots of question not enough people have cared to look at. So they are not closet *yet*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read  <-- discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming  <--- asking for recommendation on books

Comment: @Sylar both of those are closed

Comment: I just posted 2 with so many upvotes.

Comment: And now look. `This question has solicited debate, arguments, polling, and extended discussion`.  As for your examples, they are 2 and 3 years old, back when SO hadn't quite as clearly defined what was acceptable for the site.

Comment: @Sylar - Locked and closed (respectively).

Comment: @Sylar they're also very old.

Comment: Would it suck if I now come up with "I told you we should delete those"?

Comment: Wrong links. I pastedin haste. Look at these -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314/how-do-i-implement-search-functionality-in-a-website ...and.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website

Comment: @Sylar - That page came up as a 404.

Comment: Check again? Both of them are same implementation issues as mine. Similar type of questions.

Comment: @Sylar - Just rechecked. "We couldn't find the page you requested." 404

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314/how-do-i-implement-search-functionality-in-a-website

Comment: @Sylar -- repeating my last comment, your new examples **are 2 and 3 years old, back when SO hadn't quite as clearly defined what was acceptable for the site**. There are *millions* of questions on SO, some are going to fall through the cracks. Finding those isn't going to make a case for you, it's just going to get them closed.

Comment: Can you see them now?

Comment: @Sylar - Those, again, are very old questions that existed when SO's standards were lower. I've voted to close both of them.

Comment: @Sylar also does it mean anything that one of those is "community wiki"

Comment: I can find dozens of them not more than a month or two old with same implementation like issues. Anyhow, I am deviating from the point. I am not sour grapes over why my question was closed. I am just urging for atleast drop a line of why its not viable. Otherwise how does the OP know what he did wrong?

Comment: @Sylar: There, closed...next?

Comment: @Sylar `"I can find dozens of them not more than a month or two old with same implementation like issues"`  so far you've haven't found one that's less than a year old

Comment: The OP knows what they did wrong by reading the close reason.

Comment: @Sylar - Not more than two months old? By all means, please produce an example. Just one.

Comment: @Sylar: You can't force people to comment on their close votes.  They'll just say "blah blah grabblesnackers" when they cast their vote.

Comment: @Sylar, if learning about SO and closings is your objective, perhaps you want to visit the recent discussions on closings and premature deletions and things of that nature. Chime in if you want to offer input. One link is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560287/python-csv-searching-a-string-get-proper-information-writing-correct-info-i  <--here..asking for a better implementation.

Comment: @Sylar: What about it?

Comment: `blah blah grabblesnackers`.  I have a new user name!

Comment: @everyone asking for examples. I posted one above. I can find many who were on the same lines as mine. And you are taking it in a heated way. I apologize if that comes across as my intention. My whole point is that you need to think about people from around the world with all sets of IQs. You can't just expect them to figure out what exactly is wrong from the generic statement after you close their question.

Comment: @Sylar  that post was about a real proble:  `"The problem is some players get 'skipped', when the checks are performed on the variables designated as players being on the court."`

Comment: @Sylar - Thanks for bringing that question to our attention. It is now closed. Next!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640083/an-elegant-way-to-make-a-list-of-functions-in-python  <--here another. This is a clear implementation asking question.

Comment: @Sylar: That's actually a pretty good question.  At least it's answerable.

Comment: @Sylar - No, it isn't. That question involves code that behaves in an unexpected way. The OP was trying to figure out what s/he did wrong about **a specific piece of code involving a specific problem**.

Comment: @JackManey : Exactly my point. Now when the OP comes back. BOOM! His question is closed. Out of nowhere. He has no explanation of why. That was my point. I can't stress enough, this is not sour grapes of why my post or that I know better. I am just urging to mandate a comment. I am sure, if a person has enough reputation/is wise enough to gain reputation to have moderation powers, he can drop a sensible line of comment!

Comment: @Sylar: Didn't your meta post essentially serve the same purpose?  Anyone can get feedback on their question if they ask.

Comment: @Sylar - No, the latest question that you linked to has not been closed.

Comment: He is asking for a nice way. He is not looking for problem in a specific piece of code which clearly is implementation issue and I would call it gray area at best.

Comment: I was refering to your earlier comment of .."closed..next!" when you closed the previous one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you miss the part about how sylar got **you** to close a post that actually had some code behaving in an unexpected way?

Comment: Oy:  `add / show 35 more comments`

Comment: @Sylar - I am unable to unilaterally close questions.

Comment: @Robert: and yes, before I received an answer, I received 4 downvotes for asking for an explanation and suggesting something.

Comment: @JackManey: I wasn't talking if you can or cannot. I was saying, that since you closed one question when I pointed it out. Whenever that guy comes back. He doesn't know the reason why it got closed. Doesn't that reflect poorly on SO's end from that poster's perspective?

Comment: Again, he will see the close reason in the gray box just as everyone else.

Comment: @Sylar - Again, **I** didn't close it. It takes either a) five close votes from users with 3,000 or more reputation or b) one close vote from a moderator (ie users with a diamond next to their name) in order to close a question. And as Juhana pointed out, close reasons are always given in the gray box just below the question.

Comment: @JackManey Robert Harvey closed it, and he is a moderator

Comment: @SamIam - Yes. Yes, he did. Please find a way to explain that to Sylar, as s/he seems convinced that I unilaterally closed it.

Comment: @JackManey: I am not confused. I do realize that 5 votes are required. So 5 people had to do it. I am not challenging that. My whole point was whosoever did it now (because it wasn't closed before I posted it here), the OP wouldn't know the reason as the gray box Juhana is refering to is quite generic and doesn't reflect on question. hence, my suggestion of adding comments.

Comment: @Sylar - And if the OP had further questions as to why his/her question was closed, then s/he could open a question on meta to get clarification. As Robert Harvey pointed out, you cannot force anyone to leave a comment about a vote that they made.

Answer (score 6):

Community members whose questions are closed already get feedback in a number of different ways.

1. The close reason describes the general principle under which the question was closed.
2. The community can (and does) post comments below the question.
3. The OP can post a question here on meta asking for clarification.

Requiring users to post explanations for their behavior doesn't work, because it can always be worked around by posting nonsensical text.

If we forced people to explain their votes, you would engage in a protracted discussion with them about it (amply illustrated here), which is the main reason we don't force people to explain themselves when they cast votes.

Comment: My point was not to argue against my post. As you can see I just thanked the guy who explained me the problem with my question. I was just pointing out towards a suggestion that posters would like to know of what is wrong, so that they don't repeat the mistake again/frame the question better/improve upon the quality of the question.

Comment: If only there were some way to force close-voters to select some pre-written text describing why they are voting to close the question....