# "Don't comment on your downvote." <- Just the opposite!

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, down-votes

If you add a comment explaining why you downvoted - and I mean a long-ish comment which goes into a bit of depth to explain the issue you have with the answer - your comment gets rejected, and a dialog box pops up saying:

> Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be improved, please offer specific guidance.

That's just wrong, since:

- Downvotes without comments are antagonistic and somewhat hurtful (for posts written in good faith).
- You might well be offering specific guidance in the downvote comments.
- It's much better for the downvoter to leave a sub-optimal comment with some feedback then to be discouraged by this message and not provide any feedback.

Instead, the **comment should be accepted** (except perhaps for a very brief "-1 wrong"-style comments), and the message could say something like:

> When commenting on a downvote, try to explain how this post can be improved, and offer specific guidance.

The comment should remain in edit mode to encourage it to be edited, but canceling the edit would leave the comment as-is (again, except for the case of problematic/very brief comments).

Notes:

- This question focuses on the specific scenario of a meaningful comment being rejected, and on the rejection message. This is distinct from how to encourage meaningful/positive criticism in general.
- If it's the "-1" indication that is super-bothersome to people, then either this should be removed from the comment (with the rest of it left), or it should be made very clear that is the reason the comment can't be accepted i.e. "don't explicitly mention the downvote in downvote comments" rather than "don't comment on downvotes".

Comment: I've never gotten a disclaimer like that, but I definitely agree that comments explaining a downvote, are a good thing

Comment: _How_ are you commenting on your vote? Are you starting "-1" with an explanation of why?

Comment: I think this disclaimer appears when you put -1 in your comment. so this disclaimer is advising you to do exatcly as you suggest, without just saying "-1". At least, that is the hope.

Comment: @ale: Yes, that's right.

Comment: It looks like the Android app doesn't have this disclaimer, that's why I never heard of it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138189/21960

Comment: @KodosJohnson: 1. That's not what it says. 2. Advice is fine, but deleting the comment means the answer author is left with just a -1 and no comment.

Comment: You should just delete the -1 part, not the content of your comment.

Comment: @ale: The accepted answer on that question suggests/claims that the explanatory comment would be _better_ without the downvote indication. Regardless of whether that's true, that's a good argument for suggesting the downvote indication be removed, not for dropping the comment altogether.

Comment: I think you need to explain why exactly you're getting the message (i.e. because the comment you were trying to post starts with "-1"). Also, I think this discussion has already happened several times before on MSO (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/6083675)), so you should take a look at those posts and edit as necessary.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you that the disclaimer might confuse people. I was just trying to explain what it was for.

Comment: I can't find the announcement, but not too long ago a quality check was put on comments to prevent comments that started with "+1" or "-1". Simply leave that out of your comments and you should be fine.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/21960

Comment: @ale: I just added an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307416/196834) there.

Comment: @Laurel: The point is I _did_ explain why exactly I'm getting the message. It's the developers who have a hidden rule, which is not explained to the commenter, that says "downvote comments are accepted when not starting with -1". The commenter is not aware this is the case, s/he only perceives what I've written here. I'm not supposed to figure this out despite a misleading comment...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to indicate that I downvoted in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138189/is-it-ok-to-indicate-that-i-downvoted-in-a-comment)

Comment: @JakeSymons: Not a dupe, since this focused on the message which comes up.

Comment: Downvotes without comment are absolutely not antagonistic and you shouldn’t really be commenting on your voting. Suggesting improvements is great, but that’s a completely separate thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: @PrincessLuna: No, it's related, but it's about how people are _prevented_ from explaining downvotes.

Comment: @einpoklum read the accepted answer: `After the first downvote, we can't say we didn't remind them, and honestly that's as good as it gets. Forcing a comment will end in even worse results` -- forcing comments on downvotes **is never going to happen**

Answer (score 12):

Comments are not for telling you downvoted. Voting is anonymous, so keep it that way. That opens the way for more constructive comments: you should explain what can be improved instead.

The only reason you get that message is because you start with "-1". That has proven to be an indicator for bad comments, so just leave that out. Instead, focus on improving. It is not relevant what you've voted.

Comment: Replacing downvote with constructive comments with downvotes without constructive comments does not constitute "opening the way for more constructive comments". Also, "The only reason you get that message is because you start with "-1" " <- that's not what the pop-up message says.

Comment: As I said comments should not start that way. It is just wrong. The site prevented you from doing that, which is a good thing. That it missed out on the rest that might be useful it a pity, but it proved to do more good than wrong. So adjust the message if you want to, but keep the current logic.

Comment: WIth due respect - This kind of condescending attitude is exactly what the dialog projects, and it demotivates well-meaning commenters.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that there is room for some improvement to the wording, as perhaps the wording doesn't fully convey the intent of the feature.

The point wasn't to prevent explaining why you downvoted, the point was to prevent explaining *how* you voted.

Explaining why you downvoted is still the proper thing to do if you can do it constructively, explaining how you downvoted is not really constructive in general.

That said, I don't think the suggestion that you give is an improvement, even though there is room for improvement in the wording.

---

In response to the recent edit to your question, "the comment should be accepted", I disagree. The point is to prevent this from happening, and accepting the comment with a side note would amount to disabling the feature itself. While I think there is room for improvement (as with most things), I do agree that it is more beneficial to have this than not.

Comment: The intention might have been different, but the effect is to prevent me from explaining my downvote. Remember: It's _not_ the thought that counts, just the observable effect...

Comment: The effect is to prevent you from including how you voted. If you do not include how you voted, then there is no prevention.

Comment: "The point wasn't to prevent explaining why you downvoted" It sort of is.  What it *wants* you to do is to explain *how the post can be fixed*, not why you do or don't like it.

Comment: "The effect is to prevent you from including how you voted" <- well, deleting the answer would also prevent me from indicating how I voted. So would deleting my user... if that's what's desired, it's possible to simple remove the "-1" and leave the rest, explaining why you believe a comment should never indicate how one voted. And this is regardless of my opinion of whether it's a good idea to prevent the indication or not.

Comment: @Servy: Well, the current overall effect, when projected onto that axis, is more detrimental than useful IMHO - as even if I've provided an explanation, it is rejected.

Comment: @Servy - In the text as written, that is part of the guidance, sure. But the original discussion at mSO was mostly that users were getting into spats about who downvoted who based on the inclusion of -1 in a comment as opposed to discussing the merits (or lack thereof) of the content itself. If a comment is going to be explaining a downvote, it should focus on something constructive instead of just saying "-1, this doesn't work" or similar.

Comment: @TravisJ: Again, I understand and can sympathize with the motivation and the history, but the bottom line effect is that someone (who's not aware of this history) who's trying to give a meaningful explain of his/her downvote gets told "don't comment on downvotes". Two times out of three they'll just let it go and the explanation is lost.

Comment: @einpoklum - Those are rather heavy-handed examples though. This is a rather light weight system that for the most part is silent.

Comment: Perhaps a link to the mSO post inside of the explanation would help to explain the motivation and history.

Comment: @TravisJ The "-1" in the post is the only real good heuristic that the system can rely on to determine if a given comment is explaining why someone is downvoting, instead of how the post can/should be improved, but the point remains that we *want* them to explain how the post can be improved, not why they downvoted.  We don't want people to "fix" this by removing the -1, we want them to fix it by focusing on what should be done to improve the post.

Comment: @Servy - I mostly agree with what you are saying, however there is a slight gray area there which needs to be included. Not all comments for why a post would be downvoted are explaining improvement, sometimes (and as noted in the mSO discussion) comments explaining downvotes are constructive but factual criticism (for example with regards to security or performance).

Comment: @Servy - I am in no way trying to get people to comment one every downvote with this answer, so if you think there is a distinction that can be made with my wording which will indicate that constructive downvotes are still encouraged while at the same time indicating that including how you voted is discouraged; I am all ears / edits are welcome.

Comment: TravisJ: Why not just say it outright? "Please rephrase this comment to only include the substantive part rather than mentioning your downvote." and then perhaps some link to the policy, or to the meta.SX question @ale linked to, or whatever.

Comment: @einpoklum - That seems like a good direction to take. One thing to consider is that not everyone is perfectly proficient in English (you can see the rating here: https://datayze.com/readability-analyzer.php, yours is at 11th grade). I like the wording of your example though, perhaps if you could use slightly simpler words it would be a good candidate for consideration.

Comment: @TravisJ: It's difficult to try and dumb down my English. But... fine. How about "Please rephrase your comment so that it only refers to the answer rather than mentioning your down-vote." ? Down to 9th grade.

Comment: @einpoklum - Perhaps "Please edit this comment to focus on the content rather than your downvote."?

Comment: @TravisJ: That does not make it clear that you can't indicate the downvote. It sounds facetious... maybe go the other way: "Since we want XYZ, comments which specifically indicate a downvote are not accepted".

Comment: @einpoklum You're trying to write a comment that just gets someone to remove the -1.  That's not what we want.  If that's all we cared about we'd just strip it off for you.  The point is to get the user to re-write the comment such that the whole thing is phrased around how the post can be improved, not why you downvoted the answer.  Removing the -1 should be a pretty small part of that.

Comment: @Servy : But you have no idea what I put after the -1 !

Comment: @einpoklum But we have very good reason to believe that it's an explanation of why you downvoted, and not an explanation of how the post can be improved, because prefixing a post with "-1" is a very strong indication of that.  That's why it's important that the message indicate how the comment should be corrected to fix the underlying problems, not the heuristic that we used to try to determine if there are underlying problems.

Comment: @Servy: 1. Those two things are often the same, and if they aren't the same, they're usually close enough. 2. The message currently indicates that the comment shouldn't be corrected, but dropped: "Don't comment on your downvote". Correcting a comment you make on your downvote does not make it not-a-comment-on-your-downvote.

Comment: @einpoklum No, describing how a post can be improved *isn't* the same as describing why you've downvoted.  The error message specifically says, "If you think this post can be improved, please offer specific guidance."  So no, it doesn't just tell you to drop your comment.

Comment: @Servy: It doesn't _just_ tell me that, but it: 1. tells me that. 2. does it.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, if you ignore the message, and add in your own message that isn't there, then yeah, it says that, but if you just read the message that is *actually* there, it's telling you to fix your comment, and how, and if you do that, you can post it.  If you're unwilling/unable to correct your comment to follow the guidelines it suggests, then yeah, your only option is to not post it, that's by design.  If you can't fix it as you're told to, then, and only then, are you forced to just not post it.  Not because of what the message tells you, but because you aren't following directions.

Comment: The fact that you need to argue with me to convince me of what you believe the message said itself proves it does not. And your tone, like the message's tone, itself tells the commenter: "We don't want your comment." Well, you got it.

Comment: @einpoklum So when you say something that's false, claim that the message says that it says something that it doesn't say, and pretend that it doesn't say what it actually says, my only options are to 1. agree with you, proving you correct, or 2. disagree with you, proving you correct.  According to you there is nothing that I could say that would disprove your point. Since you are unwilling to consider that you're wrong, I guess there's no point in continuing this discussion. If you're interested in posting comments from now on, all I can tell you is to *read the warnings presented to you*.