# Given the positive "public opinion" on explaining downvotes, why is it disallowed?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, down-votes

See this question:

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

considering the opinions expressed in there, I don't understand why downvote-explaining comments are disallowed:

[image]

Not every downvote can be converted into a suggestion for improvement - and it seems popular opinion on meta has it (or rather, had it, a decade ago...) that it's better to explain a downvote rather than not leave any comment.

Comment: What makes you think they're disallowed? I explain my downvotes nearly every time I use them.

Comment: @Alex: See edit.

Comment: I've never received that message. What site is that on?

Comment: @Alex: Umm, StackOverflow...

Comment: @Alex that's apparently because the comment starts with `-1`. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307417/398063) to a related question by OP

Comment: I think it's unique to StackOverflow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments

Comment: The message actually does say to offer "specific guidance". By saying "don't comment on your downvote", it means don't **only** say that you downvoted, but explain **why** you downvoted. But I can understand how someone can be confused by the wording of the first sentence.

Comment: @Jenayah: But the "starts with -1" is just a way to detect downvote-explaining comment. And the red box says what it says.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: It means what it says, and it doesn't say what you (or me) would like it to say.

Comment: Thinking this to myself, I'm thinking that they don't want someone commenting something like "-1 because this solution is dumb". They want comments like "You are using foo to do x but you should be using bar because y"

Comment: Why would any SE volunteer curator care about any 'positive public opinion' from the masses of deadbeats who don't give a PHP about SE, it's other users or anything except getting their answer?  Why would a downvoting curator pin a 'here is my username' target on itself so that s/he can be shot at on meta, blogs, tattler or facepalmbook?

Comment: @MartinJames: I'm not sure what you mean by "volunteer curator"; can you explain that term? Also, the only opinions I know how to gauge are those of commenters and voters on meta.SX (or meta.SE), so that's what I related to.

Comment: @einpoklum - Anyone who answers a question is volunteering their time in order to do so.

Answer (score 7):

You are welcome to explain your downvote like this:

> This doesn't consider the possibility of XYZ

or this

> I tested this and it doesn't even compile

or whatever else you want to say. It should be "specific guidance" and not "what a stupid answer I can't believe you spent five minutes typing that". Such comments will be flagged.

But start that specific guidance with "-1" and you don't need to wait for a response to flagging -  you'll be told not to do that. That's because in general saying "I downvoted you" isn't very nice, and the particular trope of starting your comment with "-1" is really not nice.

Why is it important to you to include that part?

Comment: It can be important because a comment does not necessarily indicate that you downvoted; and a downvoter may feel it is inappropriate / impolite / immoral to sanction or attack a person's answer without identifying themselves and giving the rationale for such an act. That is, many people believe that _not_ saying you "I downvoted you" isn't very nice.

Comment: Also - your rationale here does not agree with the text in the red box. If the intention is to say "start with specific guidance", it shouldn't tell people to just not comment on downvotes.

Comment: Some nitpick on the 2nd example: Is "...it doesn't *even* compile" still within being nice? I realize you use it as an example but shouldn't we prefer " ... the compiler barks at me with error FuBar. Am I missing something". Just to make sure we set the right examples, for our Twitter followers and what not :(

Comment: Oh sure, it would be **even nicer** to say what error was given by what compiler. But that doesn't have to be the bar. "This is crap" is not actionable. "This doesn't compile" is.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*a downvoter may feel it is inappropriate / impolite / immoral to sanction or attack a person's answer without identifying themselves and giving the rationale for such an act*" They should not feel that way. A downvote is not an attack, and thinking of it in those terms is wrong. I'm sure some people feel that way, but we should encourage people not to feel that way, not to justify that feeling.

Comment: `in general saying "I downvoted you" isn't very nice` That's exactly backwards.

Comment: @einpoklum you shouldn't comment on **your downvote** but you should comment on **the question** or **the answer**. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @KateGregory: Yeah, I've heard that suggested, but it doesn't feel right to me. That is, the reason for the downvote should have the form of a comment on the post, but I believe that you _should_ comment on your downvote and "own" it. A downvote is a sort of an accusation and I believe you should stand behind it and give the poster the opportunity to address you about it. At least, if yours is one of the first few downvotes. So: "I tested your code and it doesn't compile, making your question unanswerable. -1."

Comment: @KateGregory: And if I'm being extra-nice (which is often the case). then:  "I tested your code and it doesn't compile, making your question unanswerable. -1 until you fix your example and adjust the rest of your question accordingly."

Comment: Well, we clearly disagree here. I would comment "I tested your code and it doesn't compile, making your question unanswerable. Please fix your example and adjust the rest of your question accordingly." I wouldn't say I had downvoted, not promise to undo that vote later. I don't think telling people you downvoted is helpful to them. I think downvoting is super important to other readers, not as something to motivate the asker. I see you have another opinion and that's cool, but this is my answer and I am sticking with it.

Comment: +1 for a graceful disagreement. By the way - I didn't downvote your answer :-P