# What can/should be done about "this doesn't work" comments with no explanation/elaboration?

Tags: support, comment-flags

What can/should be done about "this doesn't work" comments that give no explanation/elaboration about why or how an answer doesn't work?

For example, I've seen such comments on technology sites like Stack Overflow, [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

There are two common forms of this comment: "this doesn't work", and "this doesn't work for me". Comments that go on to explain why something cannot/doesn't work, or to elaborate with useful experiential details about how something didn't solve the problem are not what I'm talking about here. I'm talking about comments with zero elaboration.

To clarify, a comment that says "this doesn't work in version X", or even "this doesn't work anymore" are not what I'm talking about here, because "version X" and "anymore" are both useful experiential details about how something didn't solve the problem ("anymore" being a borderline case).

What- if anything- should I do about them? I've been leaving them untouched so far.

I'm particularly asking because I've been going through comments on the top-viewed and/or top-scored posts on Stack Overflow and flagging comments that are no longer needed / match the ["When shouldn't I comment"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) qualifications- particularly the "+1" qualification category for when not to comment.

Do such comments fall under the "*Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, downvote (and provide or upvote a better answer if appropriate);*" category of "When shouldn't I comment"? I think so, but I'd like clarification from the community.

<sup>One point of nuance: I'm going through highly-scored and highly-viewed posts. But sometimes I see such comments on new posts by low-rep users. In those cases, I think such a comment is fine to leave untouched because it can open to further discussion to solicit more information and improve the Q&A, and the Q&A is low-traffic. Is that a good judgement on my part?</sup>

Comment: I think we shouldn't remove those. It's good to know if e.g. the solution stopped working after a software update. (If it's the case, the comment will naturally accumulate upvotes, and if the commenter made a mistake, it won't.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In that case, the comment would/should say what update it doesn't work for. That's the kind of comment I'm **not** talking about here, because I agree that such a comment is useful! Even "this doesn't work **anymore**" is close enough over the borderline of providing some further explanation that I wouldn't think if flagging it (see my qualification: "_useful experiential details about how something didn't solve the problem_"). I just edited to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that such comments should be flagged for deletion.

If those commenters wish to let the community know that the answers are not useful, in this case by not working, without further comment to explain what did not work, then they should downvote.

If they do not have the rep needed to downvote then their comments need more elaboration/explanation to let the answerer know, at least briefly, what they tried before concluding it did not work.

Comment: Such a comment does give more information than just a downvote though, because it _explains_ the downvote: "it doesn't work" is one reason for downvoting but not the only one (it could also be that the answer does actually work but the answer was unclear, incomplete, does not add much to existing answers, etc).

Comment: @Marijn but one could use that argument to say that "it works!" comments should be kept because they explain the upvote, right?

Comment: When you say "_then their comments need to be longer_", do you mean "their comments should come with some more elaboration / explanation"?

Comment: @starball indeed a "that works" comment explains the upvote, however this is more clearly noise than "this doesn't work" because upvotes are mostly self-explanatory (the reason is either "I know or am convinced that this works" or "I know/am convinced this works and the answer is nicely written). More importantly, a downvote is a signal for visitors and the answerer that something is wrong and the answer is in need of improvement (by the answerer) or needs to be used cautiously/not at all (by visitors), for this an "it doesn't work" comment provides useful guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You covered it adequately in the question when you drew the distinction between different forms of this comment. I'll quote it at length, because it was quite well-explained:

> There are two common forms of this comment: "this doesn't work", and "this doesn't for me". Comments that go on to explain why something cannot/doesn't work, or to elaborate with useful experiential details about how something didn't solve the problem are not what I'm talking about here. I'm talking about comments with zero elaboration.
>
> To clarify, a comment that says "this doesn't work in version X", or even "this doesn't work anymore" are not what I'm talking about here, because "version X" and "anymore" are both useful experiential details about how something didn't solve the problem ("anymore" being a borderline case).

So, your question is, what do we do about "comments with zero elaboration"? Aren't those a lot like comments that convey zero useful information? Well, I think that makes the answer obvious: **you should flag them, and we should delete them. Comments that convey no useful information whatsoever to future readers should be deleted because they are, by definition, not useful.**

There's no real need for any more nuance here, given how restrictive you make the question's focus. If you had asked what to do about the other types of comments, then the answer would get more complicated. That discussion has been had on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) in the past; [here is one example where I explained my rationale in not deleting similar types of comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379993).

When I process comment flags, I do so following [Shog9's classic guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/237982/1)—and I would *strongly* encourage other moderators to do the same. Specifically:

> Moderators should generally process comment flags without dithering: if it doesn't immediately appear to be useful, remove it; if it might be, leave it. There are almost always more useful things to do than to stress about comments.

In practice: If it is clear to me after reading it that a flagged comment conveys no useful information whatsoever, I delete the comment (thus validating the flag). If it's not clear to me, and I think the comment *might* convey some useful information to someone, then I tend to err on the side of preserving the comment. This calculation can be affected by the general noise level: if there are a *lot* of comments, then I tend to look more carefully and judge more harshly than if there's just one or two comments in total underneath the post. ([Even more <strike>ranting</strike> discussion on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355593).)

Comment: was the shog9 quote hand-copied from the latest revision? "should" seems to be "may", and "dithering" seems to be "deliberating" in the source right now.

Comment: @starball I copied it from my earlier copy of it. :-) That copy was made in 2017, which is why it doesn't match the current version of the answer. You can see in [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/237982/revisions) that it was edited and what was changed. I've updated the link in this answer to go to the revision that I was actually quoting.